# Regex matching a string in a filename while excluding another string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am using regex to search through folders to find files that match on certain strings, but I also need to exclude other strings.  For example, in the paths below I need to return a match for the files that contain the string "MVP" from the filename only (not from the path).  I need it to not match if the string "Missing" is included in the filename (not from the path).  The file type also needs to be .csv, .txt, .xlsx, or .xls.

```
\\p8files\MVP\Inbound\2023\202310\20231016\BillingProvEntityFix1016.xlsx
\\p8files\MVP\Inbound\2023\202310\20231016\BillingProv_MVP_EntityFix1016.xlsx
\\p8files\MVP\Inbound\2023\202310\20231016\BillingProv_MVP_Entity_MissingFix1016.xlsx
```

In the 3 examples above the results would be:

1. no match - missing "MVP" in the filename (not from path)
2. match - has "MVP" in the filename, does not contain "Missing" in the filename
3. no match - has "MVP" in the filename, but does contain "Missing" in the filename

I tried using the below regex, but it returns matches on all because "MVP" is in the file path.

```
^.*(?=^.*MVP)(?!^.*Missing).*(\.csv|\.xls|\.xlsx|\.txt)$
```

Also tried this and it searches the filename only like I need, but I cannot figure out how to exclude "Missing" from the filename.

```
\b.*MVP[^\\]*(\.csv|\.xls|\.xlsx|\.txt)$
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Matt

Comment: Do you have to do this in a single regexp? It's easier if you do `if filename matches X and doesn't match Y` as separate operations.

Comment: You can do this easily with `find` `find . -regex X ! -regex Y`

Comment: if you need it in one regexp, you can use a negative lookahead if it's PCRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work for you:

```bash
^(?=.*MVP[^\\]*$)(?!.*Missing[^\\]*$).*\.(?:csv|xlsx?|txt)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zfO9OY/1)

**RegEx Details**

- `^`: Start
- `(?=.*MVP[^\\]*$)`: Positive lookahead to assert that `MVP` is found in the filename part (not path) as `[^\\]*$` will ensure there are no `\` after matching `MVP`
- `(?!.*Missing[^\\]*$)`: Negative lookahead to fail the match when `Missing` is found in the filename part (not path)
- `.*`: Match any text
- `\.`: Match a dot
- `(?:csv|xlsx?|txt)`: Match one of these extensions
- `$`: End

Comment: That worked perfectly!  Thank you for your help and including the regex details, that is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to match the file name with those conditions

```
(?=[^\\]*MVP[^\\]*$)(?!.*Missing).*\.(?:csv|txt|xlsx?)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/zi8sKY/1